# ZF2 - Get controller name into layout/views

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework2

I know with ZF1 you would retrieve the module/controller name using custom View Helpers that would get the singleton frontController object and get the name there.

Using ZF2 as they've abolished alot of the singleton nature of the framework and introduced DI where I've specified aliases for all of my controllers within this module... I can imagine I would get it through accessing the DI or perhaps injecting the current name into the layout.

Anyone got any idea how you would do it. I guess there a hundred different ways but after sniffing about the code for a few hours I can't really figure out how its meant to be done now.

The reason I wanted the controller name is to add it to the body as a class for specific controller styling.

Thanks, Dom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ZF2 is out and so is the skeleton. This is adding on top of the skeleton so it should be your best example:

Inside Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewhelpermanager')->setFactory('controllerName', function($sm) use ($e) {
        $viewHelper = new View\Helper\ControllerName($e->getRouteMatch());
        return $viewHelper;
    });

    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

The actual ViewHelper:

```
// Application/View/Helper/ControllerName.php

namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class ControllerName extends AbstractHelper
{

protected $routeMatch;

    public function __construct($routeMatch)
    {
        $this->routeMatch = $routeMatch;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        if ($this->routeMatch) {
            $controller = $this->routeMatch->getParam('controller', 'index');
            return $controller;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside any of your views/layouts

```
echo $this->controllerName()
```

Comment: Also, in case you're getting errors about calling getParam() on a non-object it might be worth checking if a resource is being called and exists... like a favicon. Had ZF2 being called and bootstrapped without any parameters when favicon was called and didn't exist so this was complaining/logging an error and making each request real slow.

Comment: Hi Dominic Watson, am got the error instead of 404 page. May i know how to check resource is being called or exists am new to ZF2 please help

Comment: I've added if ($this->routeMatch) in the above code to check that it exists so you should get 404 rather than an error (as theres no routeMatch for missing favicon or something like that)

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Application\View\Helper\ControllerName' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\module\Application\Module.php on line 95 ...My directory structure is module>>Application>>view>>Helper>>ControllerName.php....whats wrong

Comment: It needs to be in: module>>Application>>src>>Application>>View>>Helper>>ControllerName.php - You've put it where your actual phtml views are

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Can I also get action name as well?

Answer (score 7):

This would be a solution I got to work with zf2 beta5

module/MyModule/Module.php

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use MyModule\View\Helper as MyViewHelper;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $app->getServiceManager();

        $serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager')->setFactory('myviewalias', function($sm) use ($e) {
            return new MyViewHelper($e->getRouteMatch());
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

module/MyModule/src/MyModule/View/Helper.php

```
namespace MyModule\View;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Helper extends AbstractHelper
{

    protected $route;

    public function __construct($route)
    {
        $this->route = $route;
    }

    public function echoController()
    {
        $controller = $this->route->getParam('controller', 'index');
        echo $controller;
    }
}
```

In any viewfile

```
$this->myviewalias()->echoController();
```

Comment: I believe you can change echoController() to __invoke() and change echo $controller; to return $controller

Comment: This solution is even better than the accepted one (slimmer `onBootstrap`)! For logic reasons, I suggest placing this on the `Application` module instead of one of your own modules due to the fact that **you're able to call `$this->myviewalias()` in any module view**. As Dominic suggested, if you use `__invoke()` and return the string, you don't need `->echoController()`, but if you want to use `myviewalias` for more purposes, do not use `__invoke()` and add more functions to the helper (e.g.: another function that returns the action `->getParam('action', 'index')`). Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually the accepted answer edits the `onBootstrap` function from the Application\Module.php... So in fact, they are almost the same answer. The real difference is how each one uses the view functions (by `__invoke()` or independent functions).

Comment: If I had done this today I would have registered the view help factory in the Module::getViewHelperConfig() method instead of setting it up in the bootstrap. See dstj's example below. If the helper only needs to echo the controller, the __invoke() method leads the slimmer looking view files. If you'd like the same helper to be able to output other stuff like action, then the above solution might be preferable.

Answer (score 5):

instead of extending `onBootStrap()` in `Module.php`, you can use `getViewHelperConfig()` (also in `Module.php`). The actual helper is unchanged, but you get the following code to create it:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
   return array(
         'factories' => array(
            'ControllerName' => function ($sm) {
               $match = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
               $viewHelper = new \Application\View\Helper\ControllerName($match);
               return $viewHelper;
            },
         ),
   );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Short Code here :

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index');

$controller = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');

$controller = array_pop(explode('\', $controller));
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to access current module/controller/route name in navigation menu partial and there was no way but to implement custom view helper and access it, i came up with the following, i am posting it here.

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

/**
 * View Helper to return current module, controller & action name.
 */
class CurrentRequest extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * Current Request parameters
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var array
     */
    protected $params;

    /**
     * Current module name.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var string
     */
    protected $moduleName;

    /**
     * Current controller name.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var string
     */
    protected $controllerName;

    /**
     * Current action name.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var string
     */
    protected $actionName;

    /**
     * Current route name.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var string
     */
    protected $routeName;

    /**
     * Parse request and substitute values in corresponding properties.
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->params = $this->initialize();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize and extract parameters from current request.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @return $params array
     */
    protected function initialize()
    {
        $sm = $this->getView()->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator();
        $router = $sm->get('router');
        $request = $sm->get('request');
        $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
        $params = $matchedRoute->getParams();
        /**
         * Controller are defined in two patterns.
         * 1. With Namespace
         * 2. Without Namespace.
         * Concatenate Namespace for controller without it.
         */
        $this->controllerName = !strpos($params['controller'], '\\') ?
            $params['__NAMESPACE__'].'\\'.$params['controller'] :
            $params['controller'];
        $this->actionName = $params['action'];
        /**
         * Extract Module name from current controller name.
         * First camel cased character are assumed to be module name.
         */
        $this->moduleName = substr($this->controllerName, 0, strpos($this->controllerName, '\\'));
        $this->routeName = $matchedRoute->getMatchedRouteName();
        return $params;
    }

    /**
     * Return module, controller, action or route name.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return $result string.
     */
    public function get($type)
    {
        $type = strtolower($type);
        $result = false;
        switch ($type) {
            case 'module':
                    $result = $this->moduleName;
                break;
            case 'controller':
                    $result = $this->controllerName;
                break;
            case 'action':
                    $result = $this->actionName;
                break;
            case 'route':
                    $result = $this->routeName;
                break;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

In order to access the values in layout/view here is how i do it.

```
1. $this->currentRequest()->get('module');
2. $this->currentRequest()->get('controller');
3. $this->currentRequest()->get('action');
4. $this->currentRequest()->get('route');
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: there is no \_\_NAMESPACE\_\_ in $params. Which version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In zf2 beta4 it made in this manner:

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{

    $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->events()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach('bootstrap', 'bootstrap', array($this, 'onBootstrap'));
}

public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $app     = $e->getParam('application');
    // some your code here
    $app->events()->attach('route', array($this, 'onRouteFinish'), -100);
}

public function onRouteFinish($e)
{
     $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
     $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
     var_dump($controller);die();
}
```

Comment: Example was taken from here: http://git.mwop.net/?a=tree&p=PhlyContact&h=18385303734ab68998d155bcd4748e1c4375d940&hb=adb21fc533d973422e8c8cb8c9f7c906235eda68

Answer (score 1):

I created **CurrentRoute** View Helper for this purpose.

Install it:

```
composer require tasmaniski/zf2-current-route
```

Register module in *config/application.config.php*:

```
'modules' => array(
    '...',
    'CurrentRoute'
),
```

Use it in any view/layout file:

```
$this->currentRoute()->getController();  // return current controller name
$this->currentRoute()->getAction();      // return current action name
$this->currentRoute()->getModule();      // return current module name
$this->currentRoute()->getRoute();       // return current route name
```

You can see full documentation and code https://github.com/tasmaniski/zf2-current-route

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();

$this->controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
$this->actionName = $request->getActionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('application')
     ->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index');

$controller = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()
                   ->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()
                   ->getParam('controller', 'index');


$controller = explode('\\', $controller);

print_r(array_pop($controller));
```

Comment: Do you mind wrapping your `code-only-answer` with some comments?

Answer (score 0):

**Get controller / action name in controller in Zend-3 framework**

```
private function getControllerActionName()
{
    $currentController = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');
    $explode_controller = explode('\\', $currentController);
    $currentController = strtolower(array_pop($explode_controller));
    $currentController = str_replace('controller', '', $currentController);
    $currentAction = strtolower($this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index'));
    return array(
            'controller' => $currentController,
            'action' => $currentAction,
        );
}
```

It works for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question.