# How to get the current controller name and methods?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 1 I can get them by doing:

```
$this->actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
$this->controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

In Zend Framework 2 I have no clue. How to obtain the `controllerName` and `actionName`?

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views

Answer (score 1):

In the controller:

`$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'NA');
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'NA');`

( Second param is the default value )

Comment: is there a way to get them in __construct() method?

Comment: What do you mean? Its magically created for your usage. its kind like putting it in the __construct()