# Zend Framework 2: get matched route in view

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, zend-framework2

I'm currently learning ZF2 by developing a small MVC application roughly based on the skeleton app. Right now I'm trying to hide some fixed HTML elements based on the route matched: just as an example, I don't want the main menu to show during the login phase.

I can do that easily by passing toggle parameters as return values from the controller actions, but it doesn't feel right, so I'd like to just check the matched route from the layout and compose the layout accordingly.

Problem is, I don't know how to get the matched route in the template. Is this possible? Are there other solutions to avoid adding layout logic into controllers?

**Edit** after some good Frankenstein work, I was able to find a solution for this. I like the idea of using a helper, so I just tried to pass it the Application object, from the boostrap function in the main module:

```
$app = $e->getApplication();
$serviceManager = $app->getServiceManager();
....
$serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager')->setFactory('getRoute', function($sm) use ($app) {
    return new Helper\GetRoute($app);
});
```

and the helper function:

```
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class GetRoute extends AbstractHelper {
    private $sm;

    public function __construct($app) {
        $this->sm = $app->getServiceManager();
    }

    public function echoRoute() {
        $router = $this->sm->get('router');
        $request = $this->sm->get('request');

        $routeMatch = $router->match($request);
        if (!is_null($routeMatch))
            echo $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
    }
}
```

perhaps there's a cleaner, more ZF2ish way to do this...

Comment: Maybe this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views will help you.

Comment: in ZF2, nothing feels right for a loooong time

Comment: that link actually helped me, Armand

Answer (score 31):

Another solution without a new match

```
$routeMatch = $serviceLocator->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();

echo $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
```

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to get service manager in layout:

```
$sm = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator();
```

and then you can access `$sm->get('router')` etc.

Answer (score 10):

You could create a View helper that implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface. Then inside the View helper using the ServiceManager instance to retrieve both the router and request objects then reconstruct the route match.

```
$services = $this->getServiceManager();

$router = $services->get('router');
$request = $services->get('request');

$routeMatch = $router->match($request);
echo $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
```

I'd also recommend writing the View helper so that code only triggers once per request.

Comment: I tried this, but the service manager didn't know about router and request... still, it gave me the right idea for a first solution.

Answer (score 6):

When moving to ZF3, you should consider use this method... since getLocator isn't available anymore (and it's not correct inject it).

1. Create the Helper

   ```
   namespace Application\View\Helper;

   use Zend\Http\Request;
   use Zend\Router\RouteStackInterface;
   use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

   /**
    * Helper to get the RouteMatch
    */
   class RouteMatch extends AbstractHelper
   {
       /**
        * RouteStackInterface instance.
        *
        * @var RouteStackInterface
        */
       protected $router;

       /**
        * @var Request
        */
       protected $request;

       /**
        * RouteMatch constructor.
        * @param RouteStackInterface $router
        * @param Request $request
        */
       public function __construct(RouteStackInterface $router, Request $request)
       {
           $this->router = $router;
           $this->request = $request;
       }

       /**
        * @return \Zend\Router\RouteMatch
        */
       public function __invoke()
       {
           return $this->router->match($this->request);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a Factory for this helper

   ```
   namespace Application\View\Helper;

   use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
   use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

   class RouteMatchFactory implements FactoryInterface
   {
       public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
       {
           $router = $container->get('router');
           $request = $container->get('request');

           return new RouteMatch($router, $request);
       }

   }
   ```
3. Call your Factory on your `Module.php` and create an Alias for it.

   ```
   public function getViewHelperConfig()
   {
       return array(
           'factories' => array(
               RouteMatch::class => RouteMatchFactory::class,
           ),
           'aliases' => array(
               'routeMatch' => RouteMatch::class,
           )
       );
   }
   ```

That's it... you have a RouteMatch Helper using the new ZF3 standards.

Bye!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can solve it by finding the action/controller names:

```
$controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Once you know the action, you can have specific conditions to enable sections of the layout.

Answer (score 2):

In view you can use:

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('request')->getUri()->getPath();
```

or

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('request')->getUri()->toString();
```

Comment: I used this solution in a partial. Thanks! Worked out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

I view you can use

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
```

Comment: As stated by @Rodrigo Boratto - this will work only on ZF2, but it won't work on ZF3. You should create a custom view helper.

Answer (score 1):

Additional information about "Rodrigo Boratto" post for integrating getRouteMatch in ZF3 (I can't comment because I have under 50 repo...)

In view helper file these line:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch as MvcRouteMatch;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface;
```

should be:

```
use Zend\Router\RouteMatch as MvcRouteMatch;
use Zend\Router\RouteStackInterface;
```

I don't know when they made that change but the files are in Zend\Router namespace.

P.S. I use composer if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

My controller:

```
    <?PHP
    namespace SomeName\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

    class SomeController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function getIdAction()
        {
            $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
            return new ViewModel(array(
                'id' => $id,
            ));
        }
    }
```

My Router:

```
    <?php
    return array(
        'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'SomeName\Controller\Some' => 'SomeName\Controller\SomeController',
            ),
        ),

        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'testId' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id' => '\d*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'SomeName\Controller\Some',
                            'action'     => 'getId',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

At any view or layout, you are able to test route with this function:

```
<?php function itsRoute($routeName){
    $flag = false;
    if($this->serverUrl(true) == $this->url($route,[],['force_canonical'=>true]))){
        $flag = true;
    }

    return $flag;
}
```