# Get current route name in the view in Zend Expressive?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mezzio

I'm trying to get the current route name to be able to do some logic in the view. I need to retrieve this inside the view, not in the controller. For example, in laravel if I wanted to test for a route I would use `Request::is('admin/dashboard')` or `Route::current()->getName()`.

I've googled many times but I haven't found this answer anywhere.

Comment: There's no default view helper for current route. You can send it from controller or write a view helper. checkout MvcEvent's "matchedRoute" method.

Comment: you can find using this `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();` and `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();`

Comment: I had the same question [How to get matched route name in View - Zend Expressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078780/how-to-get-matched-route-name-in-view-zend-expressive/38101818) and there is an answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

In zend-expressive you can get the matched route from the [route result](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-expressive/features/router/intro/#retrieving-the-matched-route).

```
$result = $request->getAttribute(RouteResult::class);
$routeName = $result->getMatchedRouteName();
```

From your action you can pass it into the view.

Some variables I always use and I inject those on every request by creating a wrapper around the [TemplateRenderer](https://github.com/DASPRiD/Ajasta/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/View/ResponseRenderer.php).