# How to get the controller name, action name in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a default module in Zend Framework 2:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

How can I get the name of the current controller or action name ... and pass it to the view and/or layout?
Have to say that I am just starting with the ZF2 framework.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try as below for ZF2

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index'); 

$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request::getControllerName()

Comment: Quite handy. Would be good to have a method to call directly, but stripos does just nicely if required.

Comment: I am using Zend framework 3 version. It also works in higher version along with ZF2. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This works on my project:

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index');

$controller = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');

$controller = array_pop(explode('\\', $controller));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get controller / action name in controller in Zend-3 framework**

```
private function getControllerActionName()
{
    $currentController = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');
    $explode_controller = explode('\\', $currentController);
    $currentController = strtolower(array_pop($explode_controller));
    $currentController = str_replace('controller', '', $currentController);
    $currentAction = strtolower($this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index'));
    return array(
            'controller' => $currentController,
            'action' => $currentAction,
        );
}
```

It works for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question :)