# Zend Framework 2 Get controller name from layout

Tags: zend-framework2

I have the follow routes to different controllers and actions, that all shows the same layout and different views, example:

```
http://<my domain>/controllername1/action1 
http://<my domain>/controllername1/ 
http://<my domain>/controllername2/action1
http://<my domain>/controllername3/action1
```

How can I get the controller name that loads the Layout in the Layout code?, something that returns: "**controllername1**", "**controllername2**" or "**controllername3**"

The goal is to identify in which section I'm of my site and make some customization in layout.

I checked similar replies but are for old versions of Zend Framework.

**Clarification:**
The idea is to get the controller name from the Layout code, not pass it from the controller code. Maybe isn't possible? Other answers are for older versions of ZendFramework (beta versions), and maybe is a more straightforward way now.

**Edited: more information**

I can set in my Module.php file the follow code on **onBootstrap($e)**:

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    // (...) Other code

    $application = $e->getParam('application');
    $viewModel = $application->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();

    // Parsing URI to get controller name
    $viewModel->controllerName = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
    if (substr_count($viewModel->controllerName, '/')) {
        $viewModel->controllerName = substr($viewModel->controllerName, 0, strpos($viewModel->controllerName, '/'));
     }
 }
```

And then from the Layout code use it as follow:

```
echo $this->layout()->controllerName;
```

The first problem is that the follow piece of code should be replaced with something (more "beautiful") using ZF2 functions to get Controller name:

```
(...)
// Parsing URI to get controller name
$viewModel->controllerName = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
if (substr_count($viewModel->controllerName, '/')) {
    $viewModel->controllerName = substr($viewModel->controllerName, 0, strpos($viewModel->controllerName, '/'));
}
```

I want to avoid inject the Controller name from all controllers/actions: that is solved by using Module.php, but maybe is a more direct way.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the controller name, action name in Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883598/how-to-get-the-controller-name-action-name-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: The idea is to get the controller name from the Layout code, not pass it from the controller code. Maybe isn't possible? Those answers are for older versions of ZendFramework, and maybe is a more straightforward way now.

Comment: This idea is a clear violation of MVP/MVC pattern. Ideally, View should know nothing about controller. What if there is no controller? i.e. in a test environment.

Comment: Meaning that I should always pass the controller name, more generally the "section" name that I want the layout is aware of?

Comment: If you need this in the view, then yes. You don't have to pass this value in every action, of course. You can attach a handler on the render event. It will do this for you every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for this link: [How to get the controller name, action name in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883598/how-to-get-the-controller-name-action-name-in-zend-framework-2)

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index'); 
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');
```

Otherwise you have the same question (and answer(s)) here : [ZF2 - Get controller name into layout/views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views)

MvcEvent – get **NAMESPACE** / Module Name from Layout
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/zend-framework-2-mvcevent-layout-view-get-namespace/

I didn't test but it seems correct : http://pastebin.com/HXbVRwTi

Comment: Hi, thanks, The idea is to get the controller name from the Layout code, not pass it from the controller code. Maybe isn't possible? Those answers are for older versions of ZendFramework, and maybe is a more straightforward way now.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question but there is a simple answer that should be noted here:

```
$this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action')
```

this will return any route param, 'action' in this case.
This code can be used in view or in layout.