# Zend Framework 2 get action and id in template view

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework2

How to get action name and value of id in template view (index.html).
Need to insert action name in `<h1> ... </h1>` and use id value to select 
current option in menu.

My route:

```
 'route' => '/:action[/:id]',
 'constraints' => array(
     'id' => '[0-9]+',
     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
 ),
```

Content of the index.html:

```
<h1>... </h1>

<div class="menu">
      <a href="#"> option where ID = 1 </a>
      <a href="#"> option where ID = 2 </a>
      <a href="#"> option where ID = 3 </a>
</a>
```

Comment: Try this `$controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();` and for id you can create view at controller and can use at view file.

Comment: <h1><?= $this->getRequest()->getActionName(); ?></h1>  But it return an error  "Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getRequest"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making a view helper as dominic watson has answered in this question
[Dominic Watson Answer for creating view helper to get controller name in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views) OR

more easy answer would be available at

[ZF2 Access controller name/action from layout](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-Access-controller-name-action-from-layout-td4624104.html#a4644816)